# C# return Dictionary in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, return, return-value

```
public abstract BaseClass
 {
    public abstract Dictionary<T, V> ExtractSummaryInfo<T, V>()
        where V : Product;    
 }

public MyClass : BaseClass
 {
   public override Dictionary<T, V> ExtractSummaryInfo<T, V>()
      {
        Dictionary<T, V> products = new Dictionary<T, V>();

        string id = "HRM";
        Product product = new Product("Product 1");

        products[id as T] = product as V;

        return products;
       }
  }
```

It seems to me that this line of code (products[id as T] = product as V;) is wrong, tell me please how to implement this method?

Comment: This is not an implementation issue, it's a design issue. Replacing `Dictionary<T, V>` with `Dictionary<string,Product>` should do the trick.

Comment: It looks to me that your Dictionary should be Dictionary<string,V>. Why use generic parameter if your key is string

Comment: I don't really understand why you are using generics when you hardcode both types

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your case. Abstract base method says that key and value types of dictionary could be any type of T and V. But in the implementation of method it says key must be a string. So, it is not clear that why you are using generics.

Comment: I replace  "Dictionary<T, V> products = new Dictionary<T, V>();" to  "Dictionary<string, Product> products = new Dictionary<T, V>();"  and now i have error on "return products" "implicit conversion Dictionary<string, Product> to  Dictionary<T, V> impossible